# Optimization Problem with the Constraints Having Probabilities

Tags: probability, optimization, constraint-programming

I am trying to model an optimization problem in which the constraints have the following structure:

$_{min}f(x)$ such that:

$a(x)\geq b$    with probability $p$

In my real model, I have the expressions of $a$ and $b$ and just for making it clear I marked them as $"a"$ and $"b"$.

Now my question is how can I incorporate  this probability into my constraints? 
Thanks

Comment: Hi Soodi, welcome to Math.SE! Can you provide some details about the expressions of $a$ and $b$? E.g., is a $a$ a probability distribution? What components of the problem are uncertain?

Answer (score 0):

That is called a "chance constraint". The study of optimization problems containing chance constraints is called Chance-Constrained Programming. There is a large body of work going back several decades on formulating and solving such problems. The algorithms to solve such problems depend on further details of the problem.

Here are a couple of  accessible introductions to get you started. 
https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364a/lectures/chance_constr.pdf

https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/Chance-constraint_method

Comment: thanks.  I have checked chance constraint programming. But as I understand in this method, the coefficient matrix (or in my case a(x)) should have uncertainties. But in my model a(x) is deterministic. I just have probability involved in the meeting of  the constraint. So what is your suggestion?

Comment: There must be randomness somewhere, or you would not have a probability. Where does the randomness arise, and how is it specified?